# bitwise logical operator on enum list

Tags: c#, enums, bitwise-operators, bitwise-or

I have a an enum WeekDays, with Flag attribute on top,

```
[Flags]
public enum WeekDays
{
    None = 0,
    Sunday = 1,
    Monday = 2,
    Tuesday = 4,
    Wednesday = 8,
    Thursday = 16,
    Friday = 32,
    Saturday = 64
}
```

I want to use this enum as a list in another model.
The issue I am facing is while mapping a list of enum from FE to map to an int variable to store in database column.
I'm not sure how to do it.
what I was trying so far i:

```
int daysBit;
var settings = await _globalContext.settingsModel.SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.id == request.id);
if (adminEmailSettingsFromDb == null)
{
    foreach (var day in request.DaysOfWeek)
    {
        daysBit |= (day)WeekDays;
    }
    var exampleVariable = new settingsModel
    {
        DaysOfWeek = daysBit,
        CreatedAt = DateTime.UtcNow,
        UpdatedAt = DateTime.UtcNow
    };
}
```

Comment: Does it work for you? What is the problem?

Comment: `(day)WeekDays` -> `(WeekDays)day`?

Comment: @GuruStron, I have posted the answer.
And I think I tried this "(WeekDays)day", but it didn't work

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.getvalues?view=net-6.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So all I did to fix this was, in the same above code

```
WeekDays daysBit=WeekDays.None;
foreach (var day in request.DaysOfWeek)
{
    daysBit |= day;
}
```

just updated these two lines.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Linq Aggregate to make a one-liner:

```
var dayBit = request.DaysOfWeek.Aggregate(WeekDays.None, (a, b) => a|b);
```

And the reverse:

```
public static IEnumerable<WeekDays> GetFlagList(WeekDays days)
{
    var all = Enum.GetValues<WeekDays>();

    foreach (var value in all)
    {
        if ((days & value) == value)
        {
            yield return value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you also let me know of a way to get this int back to enum list or array?

Comment: Maybe change `(WeekDays[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(WeekDays))` -> `Enum.GetValues<WeekDays>()`?

Comment: I actually converted response type to simple enum, instead of enum array and just saved whatever is returned from Db, that works fine too.

Comment: @GuruStron Thanks, I'm not quite up to date with the later .Net versions.